# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is returning Null across requests

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
is returning Null

I enter an URL into the browser **http::/myntrac.com/udp**, it calls    
index.jsp and forward the page to Spring Controller
```

### index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" >

 </script>
 </head>
<body>
<jsp:forward page="/udp/auth" />
</body>
</html>


Spring Controller 
--------------------------
It is redirecting to the page on the basis whether user has  
authenticated or not


 @RequestMapping(value = "/auth")
public String authentication()
        throws IOException {
    Authentication auth =  
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(auth == null || !auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return "redirect:/udp/redirectLogin";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/udp/home";
    }

}
```

if user is not authenticated it redirected to login page. After authentication (google api authentication), it reaches to landing page. Here i checked SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is not Null.

I enter the URL again  **http::/myntrac.com/udp** . Since user is already authenticated it should be redirected to home page instead of login page but it again comes to login page but user session already exist. Because SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is Null here.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide how you are handling google redirect to your website upon successful authentication.

In google redirect URL try to add Authentication Object to SecurityContextHolder,

```
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(u1,null,authorityList);/* null password I am setting 
     u1- username
     authorityList - List<GrantedAuthority>

   */

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

I tried above code it is working fine for me.

Comment: Please find below Code for Google Authentication

Comment: please provide code to Landing Page also.- As per my understanding after successful google authentication you are not setting authentication object to SecurityContextHolder.